# Intuit Customer Account Data (CAD) SAML Assertion returning Ambiguous Error Message

Tags: ruby, node.js, oauth, saml-2.0, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to obtain oauth tokens in order to use the CAD API, however, I keep getting this error:

`Signature on SAML token is INVALID commentary: [Verification against Static Certificate not supported in this scenario.`

Since they dont have an NPM or NodeJS I have started to create one, however, I am getting hung up on the SAML assertion request.  So far I have ported over this ruby gem for making the saml request to get the new oauth token which is found here:

https://github.com/cloocher/aggcat/blob/master/lib/aggcat/base.rb (line 70) def saml_message...

My first stab at this is not neat, but I'm just trying to verify I can make a SAML request with NodeJS and get a response back containing oauth token.

My source code for this NodeJS script can be found at:
https://github.com/britztopher/intuit-cad/blob/master/server/saml2.js

And the Intuit documentation for making this request can be found here:

[Intuits CAD Doc](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/009_using_customeraccountdata/0010_gettingstarted/0025_making_your_first_connection) which is lacking any kind of sample of what is needed to produce the assertion message.

If any clarification is needed please comment, as I am just trying to jump this first hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after cloning the aggcat repo for the ruby script and modifying the template for the assertion message to use constants instead of variables then comparing the that assertion message to the one my script was generating I finally found the reason why this was failing.  To make sure the sha1 digest was the same and the signature was the same I had to make the assertion messages were the same.

The reason for failure was that sample Assertion Sample in the documentation is wrong all over the place:

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/009_using_customeraccountdata/0010_gettingstarted/0025_making_your_first_connection/saml_assertion_sample

There are spaces missing and the one thing that got me was this element:
           
This is not a terminating element and needs a closing tag. For example:

In addition, the xml doc type () is not needed either.

Answer (score 0):

After all this aggravation with intuit's developer documentation, I decided to save everyone the trouble of trying to follow it to confusion, and made an NPM module called [intuit-cad](https://github.com/britztopher/intuit-cad), which builds the SAML assertion and performs all the authentication in order for you to make clean API calls easily.  Also, this module is built on top of promises, which make error handling and callback hell prevention a breeze.  In addition to the library I have a simple blog post about it here: [intuit-cad blog post](http://brilliantbritz.com/2015/08/09/how-to-add-intuit-customer-account-data-cad-with-loopback-framework/)